# Is the interval [0,1] geodesically complete?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am having some confusion about geodesic completeness. Is the interval [0,1] geodesically complete? As metric space it is complete hence Hopf Rinow theorem implies it is geodesically complete but a geodesic cannot be extended indefinitely on [0,1]. So what am i getting wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopf-Rinow applies to connected *boundaryless* Riemannian manifolds. The closed interval $[0,1]$ can only be given its usual topology as a manifold *with boundary*.

That is: the closed interval *is not* geodesically complete, despite being Cauchy complete.

Comment: thanks, no books seem to point out that it applies only to closed manifolds. or maybe it is implicitly assumed that a manifold is different from a manifold-with-boundary.

Comment: @u215: look up the definition of manifold with boundary: it is quite involved.